# Grails: creating a many-to-many-to-many relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship, has-many, belongs-to

So I'm currently building a Grails application, and I am trying to allow users to create posts, and those posts have comments as well.

The association I am trying to create is something like:

A User can have 0 to many Posts, and 
Posts can have 0 to many Comments

I tried to set this up with my domain classes as the following:

```
class User implements Serializable{
    static hasMany = [created_posts: Post]
    String username
    String password
}

class Post {
    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
    String description
}

class Comment {
    String comment_body
    static belongsTo = [post: Post]
}
```

I tried playing with the mappedBy property as well, like the following:

```
class User implements Serializable{
    static hasMany = [created_posts: Post]
    static mappedBy = [created_posts: 'creator']
    String username
    String password
}

class Post {
    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
    static belongsTo = [creator: User]
    String description
}

class Comment {
    String comment_body
    static belongsTo = [post: Post]
}
```

But it would still not work. The code I am using to create this is the following:

```
Post new_post = new Post(description: "testing").save()
User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
user.addToCreated_posts(new_post).save()
```

Unfortunately, Grails cannot seem to execute the last line, and sometimes it would not compile at all, giving a :bootRun error.

I am unsure of how to create the proper associations between the Users, Posts, and Comments. Any help is welcome and greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT: my current code: (compiles, but does not save to user's set)

```
class User implements Serializable{
    static hasMany = [createdPosts: Post]
    static mappedBy = [createdPosts: 'creator']
    String username
    String password
}

class Post {
    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
    static belongsTo = [creator: User]
    String description
    static constraints = { creator nullable: true }
}

class Comment {
    String comment_body
    static belongsTo = [post: Post]
}
```

The code I am using in my controller:

```
User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
Post new_post = new Post(description: "testing description", creator: user).save()
user.save()
System.out.println("post saved to user? " + user.getCreatedPosts())
```

Output is:

```
post saved to user? []
```

Comment: This may be a case of Grails expecting you to call the function as `addToCreatedPosts` - camel cased and without an underscore. Have you tried that?

Comment: If I type "user.addTo", addToCreated_posts is what Grails suggests to me. If I try addToCreatedPosts, it says "cannot resolve symbol addToCreatedPosts". :(

Comment: Are you using Grails with an actual database, or with the default in-memory database?

Comment: The default in-memory database

Comment: Try changing "created_posts" to something without an underscore in your "mappedBy" and "hasMany" directives? I am currently trying to fix my Grails installation, which I haven't touched since grails 2.4.4 :/

Comment: OK, I changed created_posts to createdPosts, and updated all the mappedBy and hasMany directives. Still, I am unable to compile,with a :bootRun exception. If I remove the mappedBy directive, it compiles, but once again it does not work :(. Thanks for the help so far tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is more than likely the fact that the `save()` function does not return the object that was saved.

Initially, I changed your code to:

```
Post new_post = new Post(description: "testing")
new_post.save()
User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
user.addToCreated_posts(new_post).save()
```

Which did compile. But, there is one issue remaining - instead of running user.addToCreated_posts, you'll have to set the property `creator` of new_post, since you did not explicitly specify that it can be null when you created your Post domain class. Therefore, the call to `save()` will silently fail.

If you change the code to:

```
User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
Post new_post = new Post(description: "testing", creator: user)
new_post.save()
```

Your code should work.

It is also probably a good idea to replace all of your calls to `save()` with `save(failOnError: true)`, so that when a save fails, an exception is thrown. You can catch this exception, and extract error messages from the exception. Usually, the error messages are related to failed validations for the domain object.

This was tested on Grails 3.2.7, using H2 (the default, in-memory database packaged with Grails).

**EDIT** Here's an updated snippet based on the update that was made to the question.

You are running:

```
User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
Post new_post = new Post(description: "testing description", creator: user).save()
user.save()
System.out.println("post saved to user? " + user.getCreatedPosts())
```

I would change this to:

```
User user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
Post new_post = new Post(description: "testing description", creator: user)
new_post.save(failOnError: true)
System.out.println("post saved to user? " + user.getCreatedPosts())
```

The reason I would do this is because you aren't saving the user - you are saving the post. When you get created posts for a user, Grails searches the database for posts where the creator_id column is set to the id of the user you called the method from.

Also, I would make sure that you did not remove the following line from User.groovy:

```
static hasMany = [createdPosts: Post]
static mappedBy = [createdPosts: "creator"]
```

You will absolutely **need** the following in Post.groovy:

```
static belongsTo = [creator: User]
```

This way, Grails knows how it is supposed to look up Posts for a user.

Once you make these changes, make sure you start with a fresh DB - for H2 in memory, this should be done automatically, so long as you are using the development environment - and restart your server.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just to confirm, you did not use the belongsTo directive in the Posts domain class, correct? In my Post domain class, I have a nullable User creator variable, and my User domain class hasMany = [created_posts: Post]. Implementing it like this and setting the creator: user seems to work for me. However, does this actually add the Post object to the User's created_posts set?

Comment: Actually, I'm using the second versions of your domain classes, so I am using the belongsTo directive. And setting the creator of the post object is what you want, because in the database, there is a column under POST called creator_id, which is where your Post is mapped to the User. The post will appear in the user's created set because when you call getCreated_set(), Grails pulls data from the database.

Comment: I see! Whenever I simply add the belongsTo = [creator: User] directive to the Post domain class, my app fails to compile, so I guess I have to stick with only having the User creator variable... Also, if I test to see if the Post saved to the user's set using user.getCreatedPosts() after saving the Post, it shows that the set is actually empty, so it did not save for me :(

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, it *only* works if the belongsTo relationship is defined. What version of Grails are you using, and can you share the compiler output?

Comment: I am using Grails Version: 3.2.4. Here is the output when I use "grails run-app --stacktrace": http://pastebin.com/etbUBAff. Here is the output if I run "grails run-app --verbose", if it also helps: http://pastebin.com/safhkr7z, Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, it was able to compile if I add "creator nullable: true" to the Post's static constraints! However, it still seems to not be saving, as the set is still empty...hmmm....

Comment: Can you update the above code to what you are running now?

Comment: And that's interesting - have you been restarting your server? It seems like something that would only fail if you had existing database records that were incompatible with your domain class

Comment: I've edited the OP to show my current code. I have been restarting my server. I'm about to execute "./gradlew clean" or even restart my laptop and give it a try again. lol

Comment: Check out my edit, let me know if that changes anything

Comment: It works!!!! The post now shows up in the system.out! Thanks for the help, Anish!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help :) I'm very familiar with how frustrating debugging Grails applications can be haha

Comment: I'm extending the functionality of this site a bit, so that users can have a "liked_posts" feature. I've added the likes_posts set to the hasMany and belongsTo domain classes, and everything is working perfectly if I do it the way we did createdPosts (post.likers = user; post.save()). However, I believe this only allows posts to have 1 liker, and if another user likes the post, then that new user will replace the old user as the post's liker. Of course, posts can have multiply likers. Is there a way that I can do something like post.likers.add = user, or something?

Comment: I would use a completely separate domain class. Call it "Like". Users have many Likes, and Comments / Posts have many Likes. Likes belong to one user and one comment or post (the belongTo relations for the comment and post should be nullable). Also, you may want to open separate questions on SO for additional questions - you'll get more exposure, and more people will offer suggestions than in response to comments since comments don't bring your question back to the front page of SO.

Comment: Yup, I've followed your advice and did the same thing for Comments. I'll be sure to ask follow-up questions in new posts. Thanks for all the help!